# power series function of sine in python

Tags: python

```
#power series of sine function
def main():
    M=float(input('M: ')) #angle in degree
    X=pi_value()*M/180 #angle in radian
    print(sine(X))    
#factorial function
def fac(N):
    if N==0:
        Num=1
    else:
        Num=1
        for i in range(1,N+1):
            Num*=(i)
            i+=1
    return Num
#pi function
def pi_value():
    pivalue=3.141592653589793
    return pivalue
def sine(X):
    k=0
    sine=0
    term=((-1)**k*X**(2*k+1))/fac(2*k+1)
    while abs(sine)<1*10**(-8):
        sine+=term
        k+=1
        term=((-1)**k*X**(2*k+1))/fac(2*k+1)
    return sine
main()
```

I have been working on this power series expansion of sine function on python.For some reason, this code is not working. I would really appreciate, if someone can give me some pointers. Thanks(p.s. I am not supposed to use any math lib functions)

This is what I am getting as an output when I input angle M=30 degree.

```
M: 30
0.5235987755982988
```

when I should be getting something around .5

```
M: 60
1.0471975511965976
```

and for angle 60 degree, the output is totally wrong.

Comment: Off-topic: you may use `math.pi` instead of making a function which returns an imprecise value :-) EDIT : okay, didn't see the last parenthesis. But well, it's a value not a real function... :-'

Comment: You should post what you expect and what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
while abs(sine)<1*10**(-8):
```

As soon as `sine` attains a value above 1e-8 you exit the loop. You are using the wrong termination condition.

A much better loop termination condition is

```
while abs(term)>1e-8
```

One final note: You should add the last omitted term to `sine` prior to returning it.

Comment: That is a requirement. I am supposed to find the sine value up until the term value is less than 1.0e-8.

Comment: You are checking `sine`, not `term`!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got where the mistake was. You guys are awesome.